# Javascript/jquery indexed data dictionary vs variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I using a var for a type-ahead list at https://jsfiddle.net/mgjftrdz/1/ as follows:

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
     {label: 'honey', value: 1},
     {label: 'apples', value: 2},
     {label: 'milk', value: 3},
     {label: 'tea', value: 4},
     {label: 'oranges', value: 5},
     {label: 'bread', value: 6},
     {label: 'cheese', value: 7},
     {label: 'apple-sauce', value: 8},
     {label: 'cream-cheese', value: 9}
      ];
```

I want instead to have a list of AirportCodes and Names like this:

```
  $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
         {label: 'LAX - Los Angeles International Airport', value: 'LAX'},
         {label: 'JFK - John F Kennedy Airport', value: 'JFK'},
         {label: 'LHR - London Heathrow (United Kingdom)', value: 'LHR'}, 
etc ...
```

The thing is there are 8101 airport names in the database table I have got them from.

My question is, is the variable method (var availableTags) the best way to store those items or is there a way that will have faster recall performance? For example, does Javascript have an indexed dictionary or similar that can be used to store those items? Or is that variable storing them in alphabetical order anyway?

TIA
Mark

Comment: Are you actually noticing a performance issue? The autocomplete code probably creates its own data structure to efficiently match keystrokes with entries in the tag list.

Comment: @Pointy - I haven't added those 8101 records in yet, I was just hoping to do a bit of homework on the best method first.

Comment: I would leave the filtering to the database. Make an ajax request and show the matched results.

Comment: Well you don't have too many choices if you want to supply the autocomplete facility with the list of names to match.

Comment: @Vohuman - Yeah thanks for that comment. I was orginally going to do it via Ajax and SQL but after finding out that SQL Server doesn't really do character indexes (just full-text which is full word indexes) and also thinking that the AirportCodes/Names table is pretty static anyway, I could bypass calls to the SQL server completely and just have that 8101 records list sitting in a .js file. I was thinking that would be the fastest -- in fact one of the posters at a TSQL forum suggested that too.

Comment: What makes you think that bypassing a SQL query makes it the fastest? An ajax request is much more efficient that downloading a large static file.And don't worry about SQL queries, databases are fast and well-optimized.